# PouchDb not live syncing with CouchDb in Cordova project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

CORS is enabled and working.

We have a Cordova App which is syncing fine the first time it connects to the CouchDB. After that the db.sync() is not working. Only if we go offline and online with the Fly-mode it syncs again for a short time.

We have a angular.factory which creates the local pouch db and sets up the sync with our remote couchDB

```
(function () {

angular
  .module('IkasApp')
  .factory('pouch', ['$http', ThisFunction]);


function ThisFunction($http) {
    PouchDB.debug.enable('*');
    var db = new PouchDB('test_suite_db');

    var remoteCouch = 'http://estouch.iriscouch.com/_utils/database.html?test_suite_db';



    if (remoteCouch) {
        var opts = {
            live: true
        };
        db.sync(remoteCouch, opts);
    }

    return db;


}
}());
```

We are able to create and update documents in our pouchDB (test_suite_db) but it is not live syncing continuously. 
As you can see for yourself a lot of inspiration came from this [github](https://github.com/orbitbot/pouch-todo). We are running Pouch 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the sync options `{live: true}`. Have you tried `{live: true, retry: true}`?

Comment: Hello. We just tried retry:true. It did not work.  We know that our db.sync() is called everytime there is a change in db.changes. Do you have any other sugestion?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what's not working? Also you may get more insights if you attache event listeners to the `sync()`, as shown in the API docs: http://pouchdb.com/api.html#sync

Answer (score 0):

If you make retry false and make use of the error handler then you can at least see the error.

`.on('error', function(err){console.log(JSON.stringify(err));});`